# JSLint Error Report - Whats wrong with this?

Tags: javascript, jslint

I got this error and dont know what could be the cause. Any idea?

Problem at line 2127 character 18: Bad for in variable 'sport'.
for (sport in sugested_sports)

```
                // make array
        var sugested_sports = data.split(",");

            // pre build DIV
        var sporty_items = '';
        for (sport in sugested_sports)
        {
            if  (sugested_sports.hasOwnProperty(sport)) {
                sporty_items += '<a href="#'+identifier[1]+'">'+sugested_sports[sport]+'</a>';
            }
        }
            // insert DIV
        DIVsuggestions.html(sporty_items);
```

thx alot.

Comment: JSLint may not suggest you this, but I will, to *iterate* an array object (or an array-like object), I always strongly recommend to use a plain `for` loop, the `for-in` statement is meant to be used to *enumerate* object properties, with this statement, even if you use the `hasOwnProperty` check to avoid enumerating properties on the prototype chain, the order of iteration is *not guaranteed* by the spec, it can be arbitrary, so the loop may not visit elements in the numeric order. See also: [Enumeration Vs. Iteration](http://bit.ly/9GPWDY)

Comment: @CMS that link went bad, thanks for the tip though, I had this issue as well.

Comment: @Jordan, the page was saved by archive.org, you can see it [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20101213150231/http://dhtmlkitchen.com/?category=/JavaScript/&date=2007/10/21/&entry=Iteration-Enumeration-Primitives-and-Objects).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try

```
var sport;
for (sport in sugested_sports)
```

This takes care of the missing variable declaration and places it outside the for loop ( see [jsLint error "Cannot set property 'first' of undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370273/jslint-error-cannot-set-property-first-of-undefined) ).

Comment: Declaring var here will cause another jslint error. Vars should be declared at the top of scope according to jslint i.e. global or function scope.

Comment: If you pay attention to JSLint that's true. If you don't, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 17):

Pointy's answer is probably the one that lint is complaining about.

---

As a general rule you though, you should be careful when using `for (... in ...)`. People often confuse this construct with `foreach` from C#, or other similar concepts in other languages, when in fact it isn't related. The javascript `for in` construct iterates every member of the object -- rather than just values in a collection -- including methods and properties. This behaviour can often lead to unexpected side effects if you aren't aware of how it works beforehand.

For example:

```
x = ['one', 'two'];
for (var value in x) {
  alert(value);
}
```

That yields two alerts, the first contaning `0` and the second `1`, notably the indexes of the collection.

If we change that up a bit:

```
x = ['one', 'two'];
x.method = function() {};
for (var value in x) {
  alert(value);
}
```

We end up with three alerts this time, `0`, `1`, and `method`. This is the unexpected behaviour I was referring to. It's fine to use `in` if you know what it does, but I've seen it catch people out on more than one occasion.

The following works with both examples:

```
x = ['one', 'two'];
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  alert(i);
}
```

Comment: +1 Couldn't agree more, in addition, the order of iteration is not guaranteed by the [language specification](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-12.6.4), the properties (array indexes) may not visited in the numeric order, and also, if the `Array.prototype` object is extended (like [some libraries](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Native/Array) still do), those properties will be also enumerated...

Answer (score 3):

All the error means in JSHint/JSLint is that **you didn't declare your key/iterator variable**.  As [@Christopher suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886766/jslint-error-report-whats-wrong-with-this#comment10561937_2886780), JSLint wants you to declare it at the top of its scope (google `JavaScript hoisting` for more on hoisting, [like this link](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting)):

```
/*global data, identifier, DIVsuggestions */
// We'll pretend all of the above were passed in from a function's parameters
// by using JSLint's "global" keyword -- now you can paste this code into
// jslint.com and have it pass muster.

// make array
var sugested_sports = data.split(","),
    sporty_items = '', // pre build DIV
    sport; // <<<<  **** DECLARE YOUR "KEY" HERE ****

for (sport in sugested_sports)
{
    if  (sugested_sports.hasOwnProperty(sport)) {
        sporty_items += '<a href="#'+identifier[1]+'">'
            +sugested_sports[sport]+'</a>';
    }
}
// insert DIV
DIVsuggestions.html(sporty_items);
```

This `bad for in variable` error here reduces to the same as a `'sport' was used before it was defined` error elsewhere.

---

**EDIT:** It's worth mentioning that if your `for` is in an internal function, you need to declare your `for in` variable in that same context. JSLint will complain if you declare the `for in` in the parent context.

Example:

```
function spam(d)
{
    var fnTest, row; // `row` is defined "too early"

    fnTest = function (data) {
        for (row in data)
        {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(row))
            {
                console.log(data.row);
            }
        }
    };

    fnTest(d);
}
```

To make things happy, move `row` into the internal function. Even though it was technically still in scope, JSLint doesn't like the "superscope" that was used before.

```
function spam(d)
{
    var fnTest;

    fnTest = function (data) {
        var row; // and JSLint is happy! ;^D
        for (row in data)
        {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(row))
            {
                console.log(data.row);
            }
        }
    };

    fnTest(d);
}
```

---

By the way, James' concern is covered by the `hasOwnProperty` check the OP has inserted.  Take out that check, and JSLint will complain, "The body of a for in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype".  [Here's a little more on hasOwnProperty with for... in, if you're interested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4166579/1028230).

Comment: Anonymous downvoter want to comment?  I can't fix your concern without some info (and this answer really is what JSLint is doing here, so I'm curious).

Answer (score 2):

```
var sugested_sports = data.split(","),
    sport,
    sport_items = '';

    for (sport in sugested_sports)
    {
        // 
    }
```