# JavaScript: JSLint error "The body of a for in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype"

Tags: javascript, jslint, for-in-loop

I'm using the **[JSLint](http://JSLint.com)** tool to ensure my JavaScript is "strict".

I'm receiving the following error but don't understand how to fix it:

```
The body of a for in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype
```

For the following code:

```
for (var i in keypairs) {
    ...
}
```

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this to that it's JavaScript "strict" and won't be flagged by JSLint

Answer (score 43):

If `keypairs` is an array, then you should really iterate over the elements like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < keypairs.length; i++) {
  ...
}
```

If `keypairs` is a hash, then JSLint is correctly recommending that you check that you are operating on the appropriate key type (i.e., confirming that the hash is the expected type)

so something like

```
for(var i in keypairs) {
  if(keypairs.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    ...
  }
}
```

where the if is validating whatever criteria ensures that you are not accessing a prototype function etc.

Comment: +1, just a note: better pattern for array iteration is `for (var i = 0, l = keypairs.length; i < l; ++i) { ... }`. This is slightly faster due to less lookup overhead for local variable (relative to length property). This is also what CoffeeScript would generate :-).

Answer (score 18):

It wants you to use `hasOwnProperty`.

```
for (var i in keypairs) {
    if(keypairs.hasOwnProperty(i))
    {
        // Use i
    }
}
```

Like much of JSLint, this is a recommendation, and its applicability depends on your situation.  It is useful if there are undesired [enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable) properties in the object's prototype.  This might be the case if you e.g. use certain JavaScript libraries.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with `for...in` is that you will also traverse the properties of the prototype and most of the time this is not what you want. That is why you should test the property with [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```
for (var i in keypairs) {
    if(keypairs.hasOwnProperty(i) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (var i in keypairs) {
   if (keypairs.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
       ...
   }
}
```

This is because the `for`/`in` loop may iterate over some method extended by 3rd party library, e.g. if there is a

```
Object.prototype.clone = function() { ... }
```

then without the `.hasOwnProperty()` condition, the `.clone` method will be iterated in the `...` as well.

This is further explained in http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/09/26/for-in-intrigue/, linked from the JSLint page itself.

You can turn off this warning by checking "Tolerate unfiltered for in".

Answer (score 0):

take a look at jslint's own documentation:
http://www.jslint.com/lint.html
jump down to the section

for in

they do the following:
`for (name in object) { if (object.hasOwnProperty(name)) { .... } }`