# How to get the length of a json returned data and run a for loop

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I have this ajax call which its result is in a json format

```
$.ajax({
    url: link,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data); //C.L-1
        console.log(data.length); //C.L-2
    }
})
```

And here is the result

```
$users_arr = array();
//After a successful query from my database
While($sql = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $user_id = $sql['id'];
    $user_age = $sql['age'];
    $user_name = $sql['name'];
    $users_arr[$user_id] = $user_id.','.$user_name.','.$user_age;
}
echo json_encode($users_arr);
```

Now the C.L-1 returns true but the C.L-2 returns undefined. I thought the `data` returned is an array on it's own so I want to run a for loop for each user like this

```
for(var i = 0; data.length > i; i++){
    eachUser = data[i];
    userInfo = eachUser.split(',');
    userId = userInfo[0]; // and so on for the other info
    $('div#age'+userId).html(userAge);
}
```

But the problem is that the `data.length` returns undefined which prevents me for running my for loop. Please any better help?

**Edit** here are some data from C.L-1

```
Object {8: "8,debbie,23", 3: "3,doggie,20", 7: "7,dini,22"}
```

Comment: What `C.L.-1` and ``C.L.-2`` means? Also, where are you doing the loop? Inside or outside AJAX success?

Comment: console.log(data) returns true? What exactly is in the console.log?

Comment: I guess **C**onsole **.L**og. or may be **C**onsole **L**ine

Comment: So what is the output of line `C.L.-1`?

Comment: @lonut C.L means console.log as you can see I commented them out. And my loop is inside my AJAX success

Comment: @doggiebrezy, you say that `C.L-1` returns `true`. Is that actually true, or it returns some data? If it returns an object, can you please post that object in your question?

Comment: C.L-1 outputted and array with the user_id as the keys and the user_info as the values or each user which is what I need

Comment: @lonut, yes some data

Comment: @doggiebrezy, can you post the JSON in your question please?

Comment: @lonut I have done that

Comment: @doggiebrezy, ok. Please see my answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a simple `for ... in` loop:

```js
var obj = {
  7: "8,debbie,23",
  8: "3,doggie,20",
  9: "7,dini,22"
};

for(var x in obj){
  console.log(obj[x]);
}
```

An alternative to the `for in` loop can be:

```js
var obj = {
  7: "8,debbie,23",
  8: "3,doggie,20",
  9: "7,dini,22"
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
});
```

**Important is to know that you can use the next two options only when the `keys` start from `0`.**

You can count the elements in your object like this:

```js
var obj = {
  0: "8,debbie,23",
  1: "3,doggie,20",
  2: "7,dini,22"
};
var wrong_count = obj.length; //this will return undefined
var correct_length = Object.keys(obj).length; //this will return 3
console.log(wrong_count);
console.log(correct_length);

for(var i = 0; i < correct_length; i++){
  console.log(obj[i]);
}
```

For more info about `Object.keys()` you can refer to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Another alternative to that would be to use a `for in` loop:

```js
var obj = {
  0: "8,debbie,23",
  1: "3,doggie,20",
  2: "7,dini,22"
};

var another_count = 0;
for(var x in obj){
 another_count++;
}
console.log(another_count);

for(var i = 0; i < another_count; i++){
  console.log(obj[i]);
}
```

Comment: but what about my for loop? I tried this 
`for(var i = 0; count > i; i++){
    console.log(data[i]); 
}`
 but I get undefined

Comment: That means that your object keys does not match with the loop indexes. Otherwise it should work. See my updated answer. Observe the keys numbers.

Comment: how do I get the values of each key in the object?

Comment: It's already happening that in my answer. Check carefully.

Comment: I created the keys myself, so the keys isnt `0,1,2,3...`

Comment: You can use a `for in` loop for that. And you wouldn't even need the object length anymore.

Comment: @LSerni, it was the first answer that was given. It wasn't all clear until discussed it with the OP, after that the answer was improved gradually.

Comment: You might want to add the jslint check described  here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4166584/1428679 . Even so, very goo work with the snippets; +1 for that too :-)