# jsLint error "Cannot set property 'first' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, html

Run jsLint on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/SXajC/81/).  The script runs, but what is jsLint telling me when it says "Problem at line 7 character 18: Cannot set property 'first' of undefined"?

Update with sample code [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/hc7Gp/):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.selectBox = function(data) {
        for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
        }

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You should be posting code here. This question if useful, will most certainly not be useful to others if that link ever breaks. [jsLint](http://jslint.com/) does not give me that warning, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: I updated the post, please don't close.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because you're defining the variable for the `for` statement inside of it. Declare it outside and solved!. I fixed a few other warnings. http://jsfiddle.net/SXajC/87/

Comment: I am curious if placing the "var x = 0" outside of the for loop declaration is actually writing better Javascript, or is it just resolving jslint warning.